# Which NuGet package contains System.Web.Routing?

Tags: asp.net, nuget

I'd like to handle my web application references using NuGet. Which NuGet package contains System.Web.Routing?

I've [searched the NuGet website](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=System.Web.routing).

Answer (score 11):

It's not in a NuGet package. It's in `System.Web` assembly, part of the .NET Framework. You can tell by looking at the assembly of the [Route Class on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.route%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: So, is there any way to add the reference using NuGet? That is, I can use References > Right Click > Add Reference, but I'd like to use NuGet for all the references. Is this possible? Is it even a good idea?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin No, not in the current version of ASP.NET it's not possible. However, in ASP.NET 5 (vNext) and .NET Core (it's already in preview and you're free to play with it, full release is supposed to happen in the summer) there will be no `System.Web` assembly, and you can add just about everything via NuGet packages, and view [the source](https://github.com/aspnet/Routing) (and contribute via pull requests!).

Comment: Good to know. I like that, because they we can make sure our web applications are very portable. NuGet can add the references, so that we keep the path's of the references consistently in the `MyApp\packages` directory.

Comment: Interestingly, in my whole project, `System.Web` is the only assembly that I cannot add with NuGet.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin I'm not too surprised. It's a giant monolithic assembly. With the new changes coming, it's been split out into separate assemblies which can be referenced and updated separately. You are free to start playing with ASP.NET 5, but keep in mind that it's still in development and not everything has been implemented yet.

Comment: Can anyone shed light on where to find the reference these days? I can't find it in NuGet or in the "Add References" search panel anywhere. Thanks