# Which NuGet package contains System.Web.Optimization?

Tags: asp.net, nuget

I'd like to handle my web application references using NuGet. Which NuGet package contains System.Web.Optimization?

I've [searched the NuGet website](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=system.web.optimization). I've also looked at [Which NuGet package contains System.Web.Routing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29544547/which-nuget-package-contains-system-web-routing), and it answers a different question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add reference to System.Web.Optimization for MVC-3-converted-to-4 app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475893/how-to-add-reference-to-system-web-optimization-for-mvc-3-converted-to-4-app)

Answer (score 1):

The NuGet Package that contains `System.Web.Optimization` is called Microsoft ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization
```