# Which Nugets (globally) referencing a specific Nuget

Tags: nuget

We decided to have more control about which `Nuget` packages are allowed in our projects in the company. For that we have to analyze our already used packages first.

Is there a way to find out a specific packages is used by whom (globally)?

For example I remember that [Castle.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/castle.core/) is used in [Ninject.Extensions.Factory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/). But which other nugets are using this?

I would like the functionality (for not only specifically `Castle.Core`) https://www.nuget.org/packages/castle.core/#show-github-usage, but showing the 250+ projects (again not only specifically `Castle.Core`, but a choosen package).

There are related questions, which are specific for one package. For example>
[Which NuGet package contains System.Web.Optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29544633/which-nuget-package-contains-system-web-optimization)

My question, if is it possible to generalize this kind of questions. If there is a tool available for that.

Comment: Have you look at : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653715/view-nuget-package-dependency-hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653715/view-nuget-package-dependency-hierarchy)

Comment: I have looked at, but IsLatestVersion And IsCompatible not supported only on local NugetPackage descriptors