# The type or namespace name 'Routing' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web'

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, global-asax, system.web.routing

Application is based on .NET 4.0 (Property window shows the same). I am trying to implement routing in ASP.NET Webforms. I added global.asax and trying to register routes. I tried adding below line to Glabal.asax

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>
```

It throws an error : The type or namespace name 'Routing' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I'm not missing an assembly reference. I added reference to system.web(4.0) and system.web.routing(4.0) as well. Its still not working.

I don't know what is wrong here.  Any help is appreciated

Comment: You must get it from nuget

Comment: @Fred : Get from Nuget but what? Nuget doesnt show these assemblies. Would you please elaborate more on this?

Comment: Your right see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29544547/which-nuget-package-contains-system-web-routing

Comment: This should work in 4.0. Which version of Visual Studio you are using ?

Comment: @Niko VS 2015 professional

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the reference from Assemblies:

[image]

As [@Fred](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1442180/fred) indicated, please see [Which NuGet package contains System.Web.Routing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29544547/which-nuget-package-contains-system-web-routing)